# how to extract the date from text in different types of date formats using python regex

Tags: python, regex, ocr, text-processing

I am doing ocr problem, I have 500 images and I have extracted the text from images and saved as CSV, In that text having different formats of dates and I  want to extract the dates.
 from that text. please help me how to extract the dates form text.
The date formats is like this :

```
07-June-2018,08/3/17,30-04-2018, 03/june/19, sep 29,2018,24may'19
```

I have text  like this :

```
    file_Name            Text
0   01048818.jpeg   
1   0156b46f.jpeg   SST Z9R|.EPS5132K1ZL\nBILL N0 : ZIIG |)T:25HJ'...
2   01a0cabb.jpeg   FourthStreetM|lI\nP174 iirwi iA /\V| Nut\n\n ...
3   02acce30.jpeg   
4   02d54805.jpeg   <§UU[§3U.|HV’\n\nSubway#1b'/raw Mum. 5/4-<5g4....
5   02f4068e.jpeg   \-* 'r"“ \A>~ in u ‘ ..« mu.‘\nR8 Ahv'\ldIh|q...
6   0308aae2.jpeg   server: mm Slalum u\n\nmay I H3533 Dy 7\nIame:...
7   0349ff40.jpeg   m«.mw\\n\n52 M w u1m:m\n\n|‘C.uw1‘Hu w hm‘
8   0358c6c3.jpeg   5\n4 Lu A!rJ././ O 3\n.. I ..Or3 . B _.h H\n, ...
9   037ef967.jpeg   Wemms YUU\n\nEDATHAMARA PETRHLEUM CU\n\nKK ROA...
10  0406cfb1.jpeg   mlu tell us about your visit.\nValidation Code...
11  04887bab.jpeg   202\n\nWy A L/mm LNIRH smwmm, DH A IRH\nM1]! I...
12  049c8dfd.jpeg   M7110
13  04f988a3.jpeg   HAE‘-IGHﬁ.RPiJRA PLAZA\nFRDH K! [.50 TU MI 220...
14  04fa5e11.jpeg   
15  05f91a79.jpeg   "_‘d”K yous:\n1MCA‘WSter's D911’\n310 S Ilhnoi...
16  068ea6e6.jpeg   Iukul 1:01 cm\n\n,.\n\nMmuy\n\n:1 Mn\nTh‘ ‘\n\...
17  0728f702.jpeg   +1\n\nom INDIAN room\n204 Spring St\nNew York,...
18  077124e4.jpeg   "" "NR\n§u§I' I‘ﬂ»AR'A, ig tun gglilm.’\n\n(~1...
19  093304e6.jpeg   cAsA“:5>”uNL\n\n£N1x'hPR\‘:l‘S\n\nWED\n\n \n\...
```

I tried this code, but getting  some an error:

```
import re
text=df['Text']
m = re.search('\b(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\.', 'text')
print (m.group(1))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Your pattern `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}` would only match a date like string as `30-04-2018` or  99-99-9999. To also match the other formats you could look into using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to specify the other formats.

Comment: `m = re.search('\b(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\.', 'text')` maybe I wanted to try `text` without the quotes?

Comment: What @Fomalhaut said plus: why are you looking for a period character following the last 4 digits (I see a comma)? Try: `m = re.search('\b(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})\b', text)`. Or better yet:  `m = re.search('(?:,)(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})(?:,)', text)`. And test `if m:` before you execute a call to `m.group(1)` to be sure the search was successful.

Comment: Hi Ronald, I tried this regex pattern but it showing   TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object , error

Answer (score 0):

you can use [dateutil.parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) with `fuzzy=True` to recognise  different datetime formats

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
for item in df['Text'].tolist():
    print(parse(item, fuzzy=True))
```

set dayfirst=True if `01/05/09` is in Date-Month-Year format, default is MDY

Comment: Hi shijith , it is throwing an error like this ('String does not contain a date:', '')

Answer (score 0):

You can use datefinder module.

```
import datefinder
text = "uiuuiiuu 2010-07-10 love uhiuui07-June-2018hghju  banana"
matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text))
if len(matches) > 0:   
# date returned will be a datetime.datetime object. here we are only using the first 
#match.
 print(matches)
else:
   print ('No dates found')
```